# Count number of dictionarys in dictionary in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary

I have a buch of accounts stored in a string dictionary and i would like to count the number of accounts existing, so basicly a ".count" but to find the number of dictionaries created.

```
var dictionary: [String : [ String ]] = ["" : []]
let storeString = "StoreString"

func addUpdateArray(strings: [String], index: Int) {
 let locator = storeString + index.description
 dictionary[locator] = strings
}

addUpdateArray(["Account1", "Hy"], 1)
addUpdateArray(["Account2", "Hey"], 3)
```

and now I would like to see how many accounts are have created of the kind dictionary, is ther a way?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Write some doce or something

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var accounts = [String:[String:String]]() // or whatever your structure is

accounts["Edmund"] = [
    "amount": "23.87",
    "curreny": "dollars"
]

accounts["Baldrick"] = [
    "amount": "23.87",
    "curreny": "dollars"
]

accounts["Percy"] = [
    "amount": "87.00",
    "curreny": "peso"
]

println(accounts.keys.array.count) // 3
```

Comment: what your way returns me is 1 although I created 2 accounts

Comment: I changed the question maybe it helps answering it

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure specifically what property you're looking for - with the structure you gave me in your updated question, my code should be correct - check out this http://cl.ly/image/451N2u3b0z02 and tell me what you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

If you have dictionary of dictionaries and you want to count the number of actual values inside, you can do it like this:

```
var accounts = [
    "accountsGroup1" : ["account1", "account2", "account3", "account4"],
    "accountsGroup2" : ["account1", "account2"],
    "accountsGroup3" : ["account1", "account2", "account3", "account4"]
]

let accountsCount = accounts.values.map { $0.count }
let numberOfAllAccounts = reduce(accountsCount, 0) { $0 + $1 }

println(numberOfAllAccounts)
```